# New user - Create a folder

Tags: php, directory

You wrote:

> You can use the user_register action to hook into the register proces
>   and then create the user directory with wp_mkdir_p.
>
> ```
> function create_user_dir($user_id) {
>     $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
>
>     $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
>     $user_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/user_dirs/' . $user_info->user_login;
>
>     wp_mkdir_p($user_dir);
> }
> add_action( 'user_register', 'create_user_dir');
> ```

Since I am an absolute beginner with PHP and Wordpress, please WHERE SHOULD I ENTER THE CODE YOU WROTE, EXACTLY ? Which PHP file and which row ? I ask you these questions because I tried to enter the code in wp_insert_user(), in ../wp-includes/user.php, with no result. No folder was created. Please could you help me by indicating the row where I should enter the function. Thank you so much !

Marco

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. First of all: no clue who the 'You wrote' person is (this is a community with over 1000+ users). Secondly: never ever make changes(add/edit/remove) in the main core of WordPress. For users who start with WP a standard rule should be: Only allowed to add/edit in a Theme folder(you created yourself e.g. CHILD theme, or own created Theme), the `functions.php` and `mu-plugins` folder. So the answer is actually: In the file named `functions.php` in the child theme folder. Why not anywhere else? Because updates for WP itself/Plugins/Themes can/will ruin 98% changes made by anyone.

Comment: You naturally understood that I was replying to a friend but, unfortunately, something went wrong with my post. Anyway, thank you good man. Have a nice day.